# distanceFromLocation to string is way off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I am trying to take distanceFromLocation and show it as "8 miles" or "1.5 miles" but I end up with "93129432 miles".  See comments inline for where it goes wrong.

```
 double roundDouble = round(returnedDouble);
    NSNumber *mylngDoubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:roundDouble];

    if(latDouble == 0 || lngDouble == 0 || roundDouble == 0){
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 mi."];
        self.distance.text = str;
    }else {
        NSString *lngDoubleString = [mylngDoubleNumber stringValue]; <-- ok here '98'
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d mi.",lngDoubleString]; <-- bad here '93129432'

        self.distance.text = str; 
    }
```

Comment: So, the computation works correctly, but the string formatting doesn't?

Comment: change the @"%d mi" to @"%@ mi"  or 
@"%d mi.",lngDoubleString to @"%f mi.",[lngDoubleString floatValue];

Answer (score 0):

it should be `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ mi", lngDoubleString];` because you are formatting a string.